# Laravel 5 subdomain Route shows 'server not found'

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, subdomain

Want to show usernames as subdomain like :

**user1.domain.com** , **user2.domain.com**
etc...

where 'user1' and 'user2 ' are just username saved in database.

web.php :

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.my-domain-name.com'], function ($sub) {
    echo $sub;
});
```

I visited `example.my-domain.com` which shows

NB : Using Laravel 5.4
[image]

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: no didn't try later